# Creating another new Table of Contents within the same document

Tags: table-of-contents

As the title states, I would like to create multiple new table of contents in addition to a pre-existing one. Currently I writing my lab report which involves multiple experiments, in which each experiment require its own table of content.

I've read up on minitoc, shorttoc and tried it on the commands, but to no avail; nothing changed. The new table of contents in still enumerated by the old table of contents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please see [etoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package

Comment: If you could show us a short version of the code you tried, maybe we could find out why nothing changed.